# MongoDB C# string comparison

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I tried to do string comparison using MongoDB C# driver, However, I always got error message as following:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>
> ```
> y.strVal.CompareTo("15.5")
> ```

```
var q2 = from objb in q1.AsQueryable<M>()
         where objb.lista.Any(y=> y.strVal.CompareTo(tempC.ToString())>=0)
         select objb;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think it's being turned into a query and mongodb doesn't contain an `CompareTo` method. Have you tried `Equals` or even `==`?

Comment: Could you post how your  model classes look like